# Which OS/webserver combo server static web page in shortest time under no load?

Tags: performance, apache, iis, static, webserver

**Preface**
Full page load time **measured using [pingdom](http://http:/tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)** is below expectations on a highly optimized page (Pagespeed score 97/100).

Next trial-and-error step was to test using different os/webserver combos. A relative old Windows 2003 IIS box served the static page almost 4 times faster (0.30s) than two different Apple boxes running Mac OS X build-in Apache (1.15s). Where Rackspace/Akamai CDN using Nginx loads the full page in 0.08 seconds or slower.

**Question**
Is anyone aware of some published **test results or benchmark** that **compares** the full **web page load time** of **different os/web server combos**?

Requirements:

- using **static content**,
- not measured on localhost,
- preferrably splitting: start - connect, connect - first byte & first byte - last byte phases for each hit,
- where the web servers are running on (almost) identical hardware,
- in internet networks that are in comparable distance between testing client and serving host,
- without measuring caching or DNS performance,
- **under no load** (most webservers have low load not maxed out like most available benchmarks test)

Looking for a comparison that tries to deliver **shortest output times of static content** in a real world internet environment **where os/webserver combo is the variable**.

Comment: You REALLY should reframe your question, it's too much text and too hard to read. Rewrite and maybe someone will read it.

Comment: The question has been rewritten (shortened).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read this decent article about benchmark results: http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/apache-vs-nginx-vs-varnish-vs-gwan/

Seems G-WAN is the pure winner. I heard many major high-traffic sites switching to this already (since - in most cases - may serve content twice faster then Nginx. Basically allows a delay on hardware upgrades).

Comment: http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/apache-vs-nginx-vs-varnish-vs-gwan/ does not answer my question: that is a test under load, the question is under no load.

Comment: Just take the values from the leftmost side on the graphs (where you see concurrent connections = 0). By the way, I would choose Nginx for your case, because its free, easy to setup, and proven that one of the fastest solution.

Comment: I do feel sympathy for your conclusion that Nginx is most likely giving the fastest response times @ 0 concurrent clients, because the blue (Nginx) line is on top (above all other lines) @ 0 concurrent clients. But I am not assured as there is no data available about response times (in milli or microseconds).